# Initialize Google map on AJAX refreshed partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-maps

I can display a google map with markers no problem but I can't get a map to display within a partial when that partial is refreshed using ajax. I'm guessing it's because this final initialization line at the end isn't fired when using ajax:

```
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 4,
center: myLatlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

So can I initialize the map by using one of the ajax success handlers? I've tried this with no luck but the syntax is probably wrong and I don't know where to put this:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    google.maps.event.initialize;
});
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I'm loading the partial _property_details.html.erb in the `#response` div of the properties/index.html.erb page by adding `remote => true` to the links and this is the show.js.erb code:

`properties/show.js.erb`

`$("#response").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('property_details')) %>");`

The Google code is all at the bottom of the `properties/index.html.erb` page in a script tag.

Comment: what is `initialize`? why can't you execute it directly inside the ajax success?

Comment: it's the function at the start of the google maps code, I've added the full code above to clarify

Comment: Right, but why are you using `google.maps.event.initialize` instead of `initialize()`? I don't understand the logic there.

Comment: because I've got no idea what I'm doing!? I tried it with just `initialize` now but still no map. I'm adding my code at the end of the google code so not sure if that's the right place to put it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should make it work, assuming your partial refresh is done with jQuery.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
$(document).ajaxStop(initialize);
```

Comment: then most likely jQuery isn't being used to do the partial reload. you'll have to figure out how to get a callback on the partial reload and run `initialize` there.

Comment: I added the code for the partial reload above which is jquery in the show.js.erb: `$("#response").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('property_details')) %>");`

Comment: the links to the `show` action in index.html.erb are `remote => true` and in controller the `show` action has `respond_to do |format|
      format.js 
      format.html
    end`

Comment: got it working, your line of code worked after I moved the google code into a script tag at bottom of the partial instead of in the index or show action, thanks very much