# Google Maps not showing in partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I want to display google maps in partial view which I call it using jQuery. Here is the details:

In my dashboard.html.haml:

```
= link_to 'Map', preview_map_static_pages_path,  :remote => true

.col-sm-4.col-md-10
      #dashboard_preview
```

In my controller:

```
def preview_map
        respond_to do | format |
            format.js {render :layout => false}
        end
end
```

And in my preview_map.js.erb

```
$( "#dashboard_preview" ).html( "<%= escape_javascript( render "map/map" ) %>" );
```

And my map/_map.html.haml

```
#map-container
  #map-canvas
```

The problem is the map is not showing when I click `= link_to 'Map', preview_map_static_pages_path,  :remote => true`. What did I do wrong? Sorry for the bad english. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You haven't got the javascript to load it in your partial.

Comment: @japed I put that in my application.html.haml as suggested in [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). Should I put that in my partial too?

Comment: try this `$( "#dashboard_preview" ).html( "<%= j escape_javascript( render "map/map" ) %>" );` just add a `j` in before escape js

Comment: @RajarshiDas What I get is `\n
<\/div>\n<\/div>\n`

Comment: @RajarshiDas j is shorthand for `escape_javascript` i.e. an aliased method so no, he doesn't want to put that in.

Comment: @BagusTrihatmaja you're adding things to the dom after it's loaded so you'll need to initialize the map in the partial.

Comment: @japed I put [this](http://pastebin.com/0cRAn03z) in my partial, but still It doesn't show up. I did something wrong?

Comment: You need to call your js that loads the map into `preview_map.js.erb` after the line that loads the partial. But that might look ugly, so you can make it as a function and put this fucntion into `js.erb` file to call it when ajax is done.

Comment: @japed thanks for your clue, I finally found the gem in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616463/initialize-google-map-on-ajax-refreshed-partial?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering the map/_map.html using javascript AFTER the google maps javascript is run, that's why your map will not load. Try to include the google maps script into your map/_map.html.haml

```
#map-container
  #map-canvas

%script(src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY")
:javascript
  var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

another option is to call the google maps initialize function after you render map/_map in preview_map.js.erb

```
$( "#dashboard_preview" ).html( "<%= escape_javascript( render "map/map" ) %>" );
var mapOptions = {
  center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
  zoom: 8
};
var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map-canvas")[0], mapOptions);
```

Comment: I will try your solution later, however it is working now. I will try your solution to find which one is the best approach